# How do I fix missing dependencies when installing FCEUX?

Tags: software-installation, dependencies, deb

I am attempting to install [FCEUX](https://fceux.com/web/home.html) from a `.deb` package that worked on Ubuntu 20.04 but does not install on 22.04.1 LTS.

I see the following errors:

```
Depends: libx264-155 but it is not installable
Depends: libx265-179 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Does this mean that 22.04 cannot use this package since it has these dependencies?  Is there a way to install those older dependencies on 22.04?

The source is available but there aren't great instructions on building.

Comment: It means that package was *built* for use on *focal* or 20.04 where I see `libx264-155 | 2:0.155.2917+git0a84d98-2 | focal/universe | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, riscv64, s390x` available... Use a package *built* for *jammy* if that's what you're using, or if open source code, build it yourself.

Comment: What are you trying to install?

Comment: attempting to install https://fceux.com/web/home.html
The source is available but there aren't great instructions on building.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

fceux is actually in the Ubuntu repository. So you have two options, install the pre-built one or build from source.

## Install from Ubuntu

`sudo apt install fceux`

## Build from source

You can build this from source pretty easily. I just tested these instructions on Ubuntu 22.04 and 23.04, and it works.. see:

[image: FCEUX running Super Mario Bros]

Here's what you do:

### Install dependencies

```bash
sudo apt update
sudo apt install git cmake build-essential qtbase5-dev pkg-config zlib1g-dev libminizip-dev libsdl2-dev liblua5.1-dev qttools5-dev libx264-dev libx265-dev libavcodec-dev libavformat-dev libavutil-dev libswscale-dev libswresample-dev cppcheck
```

### Get the source

```bash
git clone https://github.com/TASEmulators/fceux
cd fceux
```

### Make the docs (optional)

```bash
./scripts/unix_make_docs.sh
```

### Build fceux

```bash
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local ..
make
```

### Test it

```bash
./src/fceux
```

It should launch as per my image above. If you're happy, you can "install" it.

### Install fceux

```bash
sudo make install
```

That'll put it all in `/usr/local` including the binary and all the other bits and bobs. It won't get updated of course, but if they update the source, you can always do the above again. Hope that helps.

Comment: Wow! This is fantastic.  Thanks for the great answer.

Comment: Also, I'm curious, how did you discover those instructions?  How did you know you needed to create that build directory and install those dependencies etc.? Did I miss some documentation somewhere?  Thanks

Comment: I span up a clean virtual machine, grabbed the source, and started trying to build it from scratch. I guessed at a couple of dependencies that I knew for sure would be needed like cmake, build-essential and libsdl, but the rest I mostly just figured out by trial and error. Didn't take too long.

Comment: That's really great and I appreciate you working out the details and writing them up so nicely.  This would be a great addition to the readme at the github. It built for me and I am running it.